# Create volume/instance from image error

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, openstack

Trying to launch an instance from the Ubuntu 14.04 server cloud image (https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img) by following different tips I find online and in here but have no success.

Uploaded image as qcow2 and when trying to launch instance receive error "Build of instance ... aborted: Block Device Mapping is Invalid." and when creating volume from image receive no error message other than the state being "Error".

Is there a problem with the image?

Comment: The information you have provided is not enough Christian, can you please share your nova-compute logs?

Comment: Apologies, managed to solve the problem, OpenStack was defaulting the volume space for the image too small, manually increasing the size fixed it.

Comment: No need to apologize, I am glad you were able to fix it. By the way, you should answer your own question to help the community, Stackoverflow encourages it! http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this. Because the size of the QCOW2 image being compressed <1GB when launching the instance OpenStack defaults to give the image a 1GB volume. Manually increasing the volume size to 3GB solved this because the extracted image was ~2.5GB.